# move manipulator not working

Tags: mesh

So i have been working on model but my move manipulator is working when i enter object mode the two other manipulators are working fine.

[image]

But when i create a new mesh its there it also appears when i go into edit mode but not object mode.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and revise your screenshots, post a few more  with exactly the objects described in Object mode and Edit mode so that we get a better idea what the problem is?

Comment: Otherwise, did you by any chance add the new mesh when already in Edit mode ? If so, that means you added mesh to an existing object which combined it with the first mesh which can only be moved together in Object mode. To prevent that, stay in Object mode when adding a new mesh which creates its own moveable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the few reasons why your translation widgets are missing might be that the location of your destroyer is locked. Sadly your screenshot has the properties (<kbd>N</kbd> ) closed, so I can only guess. If the little locks are dark, then that's very likely the reason.

[image: Locked in translation]